# Can a regex search inside an already matched pattern?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Suppose there is a WordPress shortcode content like following-

```
Some content here
[shortcode_1 attr1="val1" attr2="val2"]

    [shortcode_2 attr3="val3" attr4="val4"]

        Some text

    [/shortcode_2]

[/shortcode_1]
Some more content here
```

My question is suppose I match the shortcode pattern such that I get the output [shortcode_1]....[/shortcode_1]. But can I get the [shortcode_2]...[/shortcode_2] using the same regex pattern in the same run or do I have to run it again using the output from the first run ?

Comment: Depending on the RegEx engine but I would look int groups and conditional / optional groups ...

Answer (score 1):

## Description

You could just create a couple of capture groups. One for the entire match, and the second for the subordinate match. Of course this approach does have it's limitations and can get hung up on some pretty complex edge cases.

```regex
(\[shortcode_1\s[^\]]*].*?(\[shortcode_2\s.*?\[\/shortcode_2\]).*?\[\/shortcode_1\])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Examples

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/bQ0vV2/1

**Sample Text**

```
[shortcode_1 attr1="val1" attr2="val2"]

    [shortcode_2 attr3="val3" attr4="val4"]

        Some text

    [/shortcode_2]

[/shortcode_1]
```

**Sample Matches**

Capture group 1 gets the `shortcode_1` 
Capture group 2 gets the `shortcode_2`

```
1.  [0-139] `[shortcode_1 attr1="val1" attr2="val2"]

    [shortcode_2 attr3="val3" attr4="val4"]

        Some text

    [/shortcode_2]

[/shortcode_1]`
2.  [45-123]    `[shortcode_2 attr3="val3" attr4="val4"]

        Some text

    [/shortcode_2]`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    shortcode_1              'shortcode_1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\]]*                   any character except: '\]' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]                        ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      shortcode_2              'shortcode_2'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character (0 or more times
                               (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      shortcode_2              'shortcode_2'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                             the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    shortcode_1              'shortcode_1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed description. However, it does not solve the question asked. This is actually taking into consideration that the shortcode names are *shortcode_1* and *shortcode_2*. I was asking for any shortcode name which obviously can be received by capture groups. Also the consideration here is there is just one level of child shortcode. I was trying to get any match for any number of sub shortcodes.

Comment: Your original question was `suppose I match the shortcode pattern such that I get the output [shortcode_1]....[/shortcode_1]. But can I get the [shortcode_2]...[/shortcode_2] using the same regex pattern in the same run or do I have to run it again using the output from the first run`. This sounds like you're asking how to get the outside shortcode_1 and an inside shortcode_2 in the same capture. Can you edit the question and sample text to cover the exactly what you're looking for, and the desired match?